# Get youtube video info with new APIs v3

Tags: json, youtube-api

Usually I retrieved clip's info by  YouTube Data API V2, but now this version(v2) has been officially deprecated.

I used this URL to get video info:

```
'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+ VIDEO_ID +'?v=2&alt=jsonc'
```

How to get info for a video in JSON format with new APIs v3?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Depending on the information you should be able to use the following endpoint to gain the information about the video you require. Just filter it down using the id query parameter to the video id.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

See the Below URL: for example using the video id 4Y4YSpF6d6w and setting part to id,snippet you will receive channelId, title, description, tags, and categoryId properties. The above documentation contains all of the part parameters depending on the information you require about the video.

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id%2C+snippet&id=4Y4YSpF6d6w&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Comment: Get your credentials setup here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started